# Ruby on Rails Devise user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am new to ruby on rails. I am originally a PHP/mysql programmer. I can not seem to understand how you connect any posts to the user and display them (e.g. a post is successfully created with the user ID and then the users ID is queried to get his or her name.)

I am using devise for authentication.

Controller

```
def create
  poll = current_user.polls.build(params[:poll])
  poll.onefourty = poll.onefourty[0..140]
  poll.created_at = Time.now
  poll.save!

  if @poll.save
    redirect_to root_path
  else
    redirect_to root_path
  end

end
```

Form

```
<%= form_for Poll.new, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>

<div id="form">
  <div class="text_input" style="height: 65px;"><%= f.text_area :onefourty %><div class="label" style="height: 63px; line-height: 63px;">Question</div></div>
  <div class="text_input"><%= f.text_field :option1 %><div class="label">Option One</div></div>
  <div class="text_input"><%= f.text_field :option2 %><div class="label">Option Two</div></div>
  <div class="text_input"><%= f.text_field :option3 %><div class="label">Option Three</div></div>
  <div class="text_input"><%= f.text_field :option4 %><div class="label">Option Four</div></div>

  <div id="submit">
 <div id="left">
 </div>
 <%= f.submit :id => "next", :value => "" %>
  </div>
</div>
<% end %>
```

Migrations:

```
create_table "polls", :force => true do |t|
    t.text     "onefourty"
    t.string   "option1"
    t.string   "option2"
    t.string   "option3"
    t.string   "option4"
    t.string   "option5"
    t.string   "option6"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "photo1_file_name"
    t.string   "photo1_content_type"
    t.integer  "photo1_file_size"
    t.datetime "photo1_updated_at"
    t.string   "photo2_file_name"
    t.string   "photo2_content_type"
    t.integer  "photo2_file_size"
    t.datetime "photo2_updated_at"
    t.string   "photo3_file_name"
    t.string   "photo3_content_type"
    t.integer  "photo3_file_size"
    t.datetime "photo3_updated_at"
    t.string   "photo4_file_name"
    t.string   "photo4_content_type"
    t.integer  "photo4_file_size"
    t.datetime "photo4_updated_at"
  end

create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "email",                               :default => "", :null => false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",   :limit => 128, :default => "", :null => false
    t.string   "password_salt",                       :default => "", :null => false
    t.string   "confirmation_token"
    t.datetime "confirmed_at"
    t.datetime "confirmation_sent_at"
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.string   "remember_token"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",                       :default => 0
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "username"
    t.string   "firstname"
    t.string   "lastname"
    t.string   "avatar_file_name"
    t.string   "avatar_content_type"
    t.integer  "avatar_file_size"
    t.datetime "avatar_updated_at"
   end
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have the following structure:

```
# app/model/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :polls
  #...
end

# app/model/poll.rb
class Poll < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  #...
end
```

And if you're successfully creating polls, which it appears you probably are, then in any view - you could query and display the current user's polls with:

```
# app/views/polls/index.html.erb

<%- if current_user -%>
  <%- current_user.polls.each do |poll| -%>
    <h2><%= poll.onefourty %></h2>
    <ul>
      <li><%= poll.option1 %></li>
      <li><%= poll.option2 %></li>
      <li><%= poll.option3 %></li>
      <li><%= poll.option4 %></li>
      <li><%= poll.option5 %></li>
      <li><%= poll.option6 %></li>
    </ul>
  <%- end -%>
<%- else -%>
  <em>Not logged in</em>
<%- end -%>
```

Comment: In devise, if `current_user` is nil, then you're not logged in. I have updated the view code above to reflect this.

Comment: got it working but still can't figure out how to query the users information when I display the information. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Since user has_many polls. You can access polls from user object by `user.polls`. Similarly if you have poll object you may access user from it by `poll.user`.